# Having multiple things in input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

If I want to put

This is the 1 sentence, write a number: **5**

This is the 2 sentence, write a number: **10**

I don't want the input to appear on a different line.

This is the 1 sentence, write a number:

**5**

This is the 2 sentence, write a number:

**10**

The code I have is

```
number = 1
print("This is the", number, " sentence, write a number:")
guess = input()
number = number + 1
```

it works but it writes the input on a different line.
I've also tried doing it all under the input

```
number = 1
input("this is the", number, " sentence, write a number:")
number = number + 1
```

or even using the 
`input(print('blahblah'))` but that's returning None message?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
guess = input("This is the " + str(number) + " sentence, write a number:")
```

Comment: This is tagged python 3, so you would write `input` instead of `raw_input`.